# Extended class not running the constructor

Tags: python, oop

I am extending the class Submission to SmsSubmission. However the constructor isn't initialized when I do `print x.sender`.  I am expecting `test sender` but the output is `None`.

What is wrong here?

```
class Submission():
    sender = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.sender = 'test sender'

class SmsSubmission(Submission):
    message = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.message = 'test message'


x = SmsSubmission()

print x.sender
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/7LldkCAx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't calling the constructor in your subclass. You need to explicitly call it, either with `Submission.__init__()` or by using [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

Note also that as you're using Python 2, your base class **should inherit from `object` to ensure it's a new-style class.**

```
class Submission(object):
    sender = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.sender = 'test sender'

class SmsSubmission(Submission):
    message = None

    def __init__(self):
        Submission.__init__(self) # Calls the Submission constructor
        # super(SmsSubmission, self).__init__() 
        self.message = 'test message'


x = SmsSubmission()

print x.sender
```

Comment: Try now. I don't know why it doesn't run in that online interpreter but I just tested it myself using the edited version and it works.